# C# How to get the size of the form border buttons [Minimize/Maximize/Close]

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to set the minimum size of my forms programatically, to do that, I measure:

- The left icon of the form; [Ok]
- The title of the form; [Ok]
- The size of the right buttons (Minimize/Maximize/Close) [Problem]

The button sizes change between OS, and I dont want to fix a value... Any sugestion to get the size of the corner buttons?

Comment: `Form.ClientSize` is the size excluding frame & title bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really simple!

```
Size s = SystemInformation.CaptionButtonSize;
```

Comment: SystemInformation.CaptionButtonSize.Width give a value of 36... But my Close button has 45, and maximize/minimize button has size of 27... :(

But SystemInformation.MinimumWindowSize seems to be a final ansfer for my needs!

Thanks for giving me the right direction! :)

Comment: That's interesting, it appears to be an average of those two. I don't think I've ever observed this. Not very useful in that case.