# Getting system buttons size

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there a way to find out the size of the system buttons (minimize, maximize or close button) in a desktop application? Thanks.

I already tried different scenarios, like WindowChrome class, but nothing works well.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/479332/1207195

Comment: [In winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28477441/1997232) (not sure if it's the same in wpf). In any case try to explain *"nothing works well"* with code and screenshots.

Comment: @Sinatr If there's no other way then the OP might consider adding a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`. But mixing WPF and WinForms is generally considered a bad practice.